# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.ImportTab_jsp

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, tomcat, classpath

We are getting below exception

```
2024-03-13 11:42:00,723 ERROR | Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.ImportTab_jsp] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.ImportTab_jsp
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:129)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:58)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:151)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:189)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:410)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at com.comptel.catalog.support.filter.OperationClientRestFilter.doFilter(OperationClientRestFilter.java:86)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at com.comptel.catalog.support.filter.JwtSecurityChainFilter.doFilter(JwtSecurityChainFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
```

In our Project we are using `Springboot3.2.2` with embedded `tomcat10` and Java17.Many times we are getting above expectations when accessing the jsp pages and once this issue come that page wont access upto the time we wont restart the application,this issue is coming occasionally .

What I've tried:

1. Deleted the /tmp/Tomcat directory and checked but 500 error is not coming, All Jsp pages working fine without any issue.
2. We are using `javax.servlet-api-4.0.1` and `jakarta.servlet-api-5.0.0`. Will this create any issue.

Any one can please help how to reproduce this issue or how to fix this? Why sometime a particular JSP throwing `500(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)`.

Comment: 2 will be an issue as those are far from compatible. Why are you even defining those they should come in with the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in use.

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you mean we wont required `javax.servlet-api-4.0.1` and `jakarta.servlet-api-5.0.0` . Or we wont require only `javax.servlet-api-4.0.1` now. We have to add  `javax.servlet-api-4.0.1`  because `hazelcast-all-4.2.8.jar` . Just for your information previously springboot2.7.2 and Java8 also we are getting this issue.

Comment: Spring Boot 3 requires JakartaEE to work correctly, so you need to upgrade your depnendencies as well and not just simply upgrade Spring Boot (when doing Spring Boot 3).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your response . Is this possible to explain why only JSP throwing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException occasionally and not all ways?

Comment: You have `ClassNotFoundException`. The jasper servlet is trying to load a class. At this point you should go to debugger and see why the class is not loaded. There could be many issues but you didn't point to any of them. "When you get a `ClassNotFoundException`, it means the JVM has traversed the entire classpath and not found the class you've attempted to reference. The solution, as so often in the Java world, is to check your classpath". Very great solution.

Comment: @RomanC Thanks for input,this issue is not directly related to java class its related to JSP page converted to java class . This issue is happening occasionally and not able to reproduce by my own way.

Comment: What is the cause of this? If the JSP fails to convert to a java class then I would convert it manually and add it to classpath. You should investigate the problem and give us debugging details. We have not enough information about your project or server, so the answer is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully replicated the issue. Kindly observe how it can be reproduced.
So what exactly Happening ?

1- Started Application.

2- Application will create a tomcat directory under tmp directory in Linux

```
/tmp/tomcat.47003.2497552974163365448/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT/org/apache/jsp/
```

3- By default it will compile and copy  `Login_jsp.java` & `Login_jsp.class` inside above folder.

4- Now user Login into UI( ).

5- It will compile and copy  `Index_jsp.jav`a & `Index_jsp.class` inside above folder.

Lets understand this with a issue .

Now take this scenario as a example and lets try to understand what happened here

1- Application was up and running(It may be started today or running from couple of days or week or months)
2-  So tomcat created a folder structure

```
/tmp/tomcat.47003.2497552974163365448/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/
```

3- By default(As Servlet know `login.jsp` is entry point of application) compiled and  copied the `Login_jsp.class` and `Login_jsp.java` under jsp folder.

4- Now some of the  OS process OR cron job OR something else(Not sure who is doing this) deleted the

```
/tmp/tomcat.47003.2497552974163365448/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/
```

5- Now if someone will access the application he will able to see login page ,because its compiled and tomcat holding `Login.jsp` reference some other place as well.  But after Login he will not able to see the `Index.jsp` page because before it should compile this jsp, `/tmp/tomcat` directory deleted(By any process or manually or some other way) .

6- Due to this after login ,user will get 500 error

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.Index_jsp

Now we have to monitor who actually deleting  `/tmp/tomcat` directory

Or

We can use `server.tomcat.basedir`
[Tomcat base directory. If not specified, a temporary directory is used.]